Is there a relationship between these two integrals?
I’m trying to find a (hopefully simple) relationship between these two integrals. Expressing the second integral in terms of the first one would be good.
$\displaystyle \int_0^a f(x) (1-f(x)) dx$
and
$\displaystyle \int_0^a f(x)^2 (1-f(x)) dx$
where $0 \le f(x) \le 1 $ and $f(x)$ is smooth and continuous. I keep trying to integrate by parts, but I get nowhere.

The second one is not larger than the first. No other relation holds between them.

Thank you, @vanderWolf. Can you explain why "no other relation holds between them" is intuitively obvious for you?

You may want to reverse those inequalities but indeed, at that general level you can't deduce any algebraic relationship.

fixed it, thank you

You can write an algebraic relationship between the derivatives with respect to $a.$ That relationship gives rise to a nonlinear differential equation between the two integrals as a function of $a.$ Nonlinear differential equations rarely have closed form solutions.

Ok, thank you, I follow the logic of the last two sentences, but I don't see how to get the algebraic relation.  What should I be taking the derivative with respect to a of?

If $0 \le f(x) \le 1$  for $x\in [0,a)$, then $f^2(x)(1-f(x)) \le f(x)(1-f(x))$. If you denote $$I_1 = \int_0^{a} f(x)(1-f(x))dx, I_2 = \int_0^{a} f^2(x)(1-f(x))dx  $$
then clearly $I_1 \ge I_2$ (equality for $f=1$). Some examples $$f(x)=e^{-x}, a= \infty,  \quad I_1 = \frac{1}{2} > I_2 = \frac{1}{6} \\ f(x) = \frac{1+\sin{x}}{2}, a = \frac{\pi}{2}\quad I_1 = \frac{\pi}{16} > I_2 = \frac{\pi}{32}+\frac{1}{24}\\ 
f(x) = \cos^2{x}, a = \pi, \quad I_1 = \frac{\pi}{8} > I_2 = \frac{\pi}{16} $$
Addendum: If we consider the integrals as functions, then $$ I_1(x) = \int_0^x f(t)(1-f(t))dt,\quad I_2(x) = \int_0^x f^2(t)(1-f(t))dt $$
then $\frac{dI_1}{dx}(x) = f(x)(1-f(x)) > 0$ and  $\frac{dI_2}{dx}(x) = f^2(x)(1-f(x))$. This implies  $I_2'(x) = f(x)I_1'(x)$ and $$ I_2(x) = \int_0^x  f(t)I_1'(t) dt.$$
This is probably what @Lieven meant.
Addendum 2: If you use generalized mean value theorem, then
$$I_1 = f(c)I_2$$
for some $c$ in $(0,a)$.

Thank you, I agree with this, but you can you connect it with Lieven's comment above about deriving a nonlinear differential equation or comment on that?

Let $$I_1 = \int_0^a f(x) - f(x)^2 \,dx$$ and $$
I_2 = \int_0^a f(x)^2 - f(x)^3 \,dx
$$
(These are your first and second integrals, respectively.) There is no algebraic relationship that can be deduced from this alone. The best we can do is note that $$
I_1+I_2 = \int_0^a f(x) - f(x)^3\,dx = \int_0^a f(x)(1-f(x)^2)
$$
which can be any number between $0$ and $a \frac{2}{3\sqrt 3}$ (note that $\frac{2}{3\sqrt 3}$ is the maximum of $x-x^3$ on $(0,1)$).
We also have that $$
I_1 - I_2 = \int_0^a f(x)-2f(x)^2+f(x)^3\,dx = \int_0^a f(x)(1-f(x))^2\,dx
$$
which takes on any value between $0$ and $\frac4{27}a$.

What is wrong with this argument : $0\le f(x)\le 1$ for $x \in [0,a]$ implies $f(x)^2 (1-f(x)) \le f(x)(1-f(x))$, therefore $I_1>I_2$

I got the order backwards :P
